# How to detect a delimiter while reading from a socket file descriptor in C?

Tags: c, sockets

In C, while reading into a buffer from a socket file descriptor, how do I make the read stop if a delimiter is detected? Let's assume the delimiter is a '>' character.

```
read(socket_filedes, buffer, MAXSZ);
/* stop if delimiter '>' is detected */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read()` function does not examine the data it transfers them from source to buffer.  You cannot force it to stop transferring data at a specific character or characters if it would not otherwise have stopped there.

On the other hand, it is important to recognize that `read()` does not necessarily read the full number of bytes specified in any case.  On one hand, that means that you need to be prepared to run `read()` calls in a loop to collect all the data you expect, but on the other hand it means that you can usually expect that if `read()` has already transferred at least one byte then it will return when no more data are immediately available to transfer.  Thus, if the sender stops sending data after the delimiter, then `read()` will probably stop reading after that delimiter.

If you cannot rely on the sender to break up the transmission as you require, then you have the option of reading one byte at a time.  That can be awfully inefficient, however.  The more usual solution is to do the job in two stages: (1) perform fast, block-wise `read()`s from the kernel into a userspace buffer, and then (2) parse the buffer contents via your userspace code.  This is basically what readable C streams do when using a buffer.

Answer (score 5):

You have two options here:

- Read a single byte at a time until you encounter a delimiter.  This is likely to be very inefficient.
- Read in a full buffer's worth of data at a time, then look for the delimiter there.  When you find it, save off the remaining data in another buffer and process the data you want.  When you're ready to read again, put the saved data back in the buffer and call `read` with the address of the next available byte in the buffer.